# How to allow Razorpay Webhook in Cloudflare bot-fight-mode?

Tags: webhooks, cloudflare, razorpay

In our Application, We have enabled Razorpay Webhook for seamless payment.

During development testing I have used ngrok. It is working fine.

My production server is protected by cloudflare and enabled with bot-fight-mode.

**When the payment is success. POST request is sent by razor-pay web-hook. But it has been blocked by cloudflare bot-fight-mode.**
[image: Cloudflare blocked info]

***So I created a firewall rule to allow it.***
[image: Firewall rule]

Still Webhook is blocked by cloudflare?

What should I need to do to allow razorpay webhook to bypass cloudflare by blocking other bots?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I came here looking for an answer too but I don't think it is possible unless you have an enterprise account:
https://community.cloudflare.com/t/questions-about-cloudflare-super-bot-fight-mode/256213/40

Whilst this thread is referring to Super Bot Mode I believe the principal is the same and it is only with an enterprise account that you can chose which URIs to target and bots to allow through.

Update: I've ended up disabling Bot Fight Mode and will use Fail2Ban on my server and the CloudFlare API to block the IP addresses at their end.